# Create PDF from selected images using automator service

Tags: bash, macos, automation, applescript

I found many topics on that but none of the solutions seem to fit what i want to do or they don't work.

I want to select multiple images in a folder in a finder window.
I want to right-click the selection and run a Service to create a PDF using those images in the same folder those images are in.

I don't know how to get the directory the images are placed in.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your selected file could be from different folders, you must loop to each image and get parent folder as bellow :

```
tell application "Finder"
set myFIles to selection -- read your selection of images   
repeat with aFile in myFIles -- loop for each selecgted image
    set ParentFolder to container of aFile -- get folder which contains that image
end repeat
end tell
```